# PhpSpreadsheet - Can I add digital signature to xls file in PHP?

Tags: php, digital-signature, phpspreadsheet

I use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet
I need to add digital signature to xls document to verify authenticity of document. Is it possible with this or maybe other PHP library? Can anyone point me a direction how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Digital signatures are not supported in PhpSpreadsheet.

But in case you want macros signed with a certificate, then those are supported in PhpSpreadsheet Xlsx writer. But that feature is not documented. To understand how to use, refer to the [commit that introduced it](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/252). It should be something like:

$spreadsheet->setMacrosCertificate($certificate);